# Apparently-aliased tags [buildconfig] and [buildconfiguration]

Tags: support, tags, clean-up

These tags appear to be duplicates.  The tag [buildconfiguration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/buildconfiguration) is more widely adopted with 100 vs. 42 tagged questions, so I suggest merging the tag [buildconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/buildconfig) into [buildconfiguration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/buildconfiguration).

Comment: Can we add a hyphen: [build-configuration]?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but one of them is used more widely along with the android tag and the other with visual studio... neither has excerpt. Just what knowledge is one supposed to have to answer any of those questions?

Comment: @Braiam A build configuration (or build config) is a general term for the collection of settings and parameters used to specify how an IDE project is to be built.

Comment: Well, that's not the usage is given right now for both tags, [buildconfig] is a [class generated from Android Developer Tools](http://www.digipom.com/be-careful-with-buildconfig-debug/), which seems to be the main usage, while [buildconfiguration] is used in a more generic way (some menu or option or action) through mostly related to Visual Studio.

Comment: @Braiam: See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Braiam's comment is apparently correct. So, I have now edited the two tag wikis:

- [buildconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/buildconfig)
- [buildconfiguration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/buildconfiguration)

... so that each tag has a distinctive description. However, the [buildconfiguration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/buildconfiguration) tag should definitely be renamed [build-configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/build-configuration).